# Error in executing DTCWT function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, wavelet-transform

**Hello everyone !**

I'm trying to implement the dual tree complex wavelet transform **DT CWT**. I use this function  :

```
dtwavexfm2('textured_image.jpg',3,'near_sym_b','qshift_b');
```

but i get this as an error :

```
Undefined function 'conv2' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in colfilter (line 22)
 Y = conv2(X(xe,:),h(:),'valid');

Error in dtwavexfm2 (line 85)
Lo = colfilter(X,h0o).';
```

Can someone help me

Comment: As far as I can tell, `dtwavexfm2` is not a MATLAB built-in nor toolbox function. Where is it from? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: If it's [this function](https://github.com/rkwitt/coptex/blob/master/mfiles/dtcwt/dtwavexfm2.m), your first input is wrong.

Comment: as mentioned in the documentation in your link the first argument 'X' is an image !

Comment: Yes, it does mention that. `'textured_image.jpg'` is a character array. You need to [load your image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/importing-images.html) into MATLAB. Voting to close as a typographical error.

Comment: it works perfectly ! thank you for your help and time